# Patching Sun Solaris

Tags: solaris

Hi recently we have an application issue which requires patching of sun solaris.

Problem is that there are many zones created in this solaris server which are used by other applications.

So if it is possible that certain patches could affect the current applications.

What is the best way to handle this kind of situation?

Comment: Why are people voting to close this?  He's asking a completely programming related question.

Comment: "many zones created in this solaris server which are used by other applications." = means what?

Answer (score 3):

If you're patching the kernel, then your patches affect everyone: there's only one copy of the kernel.

If you're patching application software, then you can apply *those* patches to affect only certain zones.

Have a look at the [Zones FAQ.](http://opensolaris.org/os/community/zones/faq/#patching)

Comment: The code affects everyone but it's entirely possible to flag a process for a special case in the code.

Comment: And on that special case, what happens?  It's not like you can then change kernels.  Patches applied to the kernel *will affect all zsones.*

Comment: You apply the flag to the applications you want to be included in the fix.  Yes, the same kernel code will be running everywhere, but that doesn't at all prevent you from special-casing.

Answer (score 0):

The solution really depends entirely on where the problem lies and what sort of fix you're applying.  In many cases, if the problem is in the kernel, you can patch it in such a way that the patch will only apply to a process with a given flag.  If it's in a library or some such, you could have a harder time.  In short, we really need a lot more info to give you a solid answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is the patch you need to apply timezone-related?  If not, you may be able to only apply the one patch.

Your best bet is to set up a staging system that's software-wise identical to this box, get it working, and then install your patches and test.

Answer (score 0):

One trick I have used is to make the global "forget" about its zones. Stop the zones, get them to the "installed state", thendelete them from /etc/zones.index.xml (after taking a backup copy of that one, of course). You can now perform the upgrade, without affecting the zones. After patching and rebooting, reinstall the original index.xml and attach the zones with the -F option; otherwise they will apply the patches when attached.
But mind you, this is not a situation toy really wish to keep forever. Sooner or later you really ought to bring the zones to latest level, too.
And before I forget: this trick does not work if you have "sparse" zones.